# SQL Query (max of sum per year)

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, max

I will try to describe my problem here. Let's say that i have 3 tables:

**1.** sales

- salesID (PK)
- productID(FK) - FK that points to the sold product
- storeID(FK) - FK that points to the store that sold the product
- month - month in which the product was sold
- year - year in which the product was sold
- amount - amount(of money) for which the product was sold

**2.** product

- productID (PK)
- productName

**3.** store

- storeID (PK)
- storeName

---

I need the following query: **For every store show the top selling product in that store for the specified year.** So the result should look something like:

```
STORE    PRODUCT    AMOUNT
store1   product1   XXX amount
store2   product2   YYY amount
store3   product1   XYX amount
```

Where each amount would be the highest sum of all amounts in that year.

What I can do now is:

```
  SELECT store.storeName
       , product.ProductName
       , SUM(sales.ammount)
    FROM sales
    JOIN product ON sales.productID = product.productID
    JOIN store   ON sales.storeID   = store.storeID
GROUP BY store.storeName
       , product.ProductName
   WHERE sales.year = 'XXXX'
       ;
```

Where I get a sum per product and per store. After this I can use the cursor to go thru the entire table row by row and check which one has the highest amount for that store.

But I was wondering if it is possible to do that in a 'simple' query?

I'm using SQL Developer for Oracle 11g database.
And I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not terribly familiar with Oracle, but perhaps something like:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT store.storeName
                   , product.ProductName
                   , SUM(sales.ammount) as sales_amount
              FROM sales
              JOIN product ON sales.productID = product.productID
              JOIN store ON sales.storeID = store.storeID
              WHERE sales.year = 'XXXX'                  
              GROUP BY store.storeName, product.ProductName
              )
SELECT a.*
FROM cte a
JOIN (SELECT storeName
            , MAX(sales_amount) as Max_Sales
      FROM cte
      GROUP BY storeName
      )b
  ON a.storeName = b.StoreName
  AND a.sales_amount = b.Max_Sales;
```

If there's a tie that returns both entries, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead to limit to one result per storeName .

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is `sales_amount = SUM(sales.amount)` not valid aliasing in oracle, or you just consider it to be non-standard?

Comment: It is non-standard **and** not valid in any DBMS except SQL Server.

Comment: Btw: SQL Server does support the standard syntax as well.

Comment: @a_horse, it's actually perfectly fine in Oracle. The only thing wrong with the statement is that the WHERE in the CTE should be before the GROUP BY.

Comment: @a_horse, sorry, I got in late and didn't notice the edits. As it stands now, the answer good. Your comment was spot on.

Comment: Glad to hear, consider marking this question as answered by ticking the checkmark.